# How do I display all commits I've made on all branches?

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to see all the commits I've made on all branches, along with what branch each commit was made on. I've tried `git log --branches --author="My Name"`, but that doesn't tell me what branches I've made each commit on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using gitk produces a reasonably good result i think.

```
gitk --all --author="username"
```

But again, the commits are not owned by a particular branch so when viewing all branches and filtering out your commits you might see a ton of branches you never even knew existed, depending on the complexity of the repository. For a smaller repo i would imagine this gets quite readable.

I guess the git log counterpart would be something like

```
git log --oneline --decorate --all --author="username"
```

I don't find it as readable for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! This works pretty well. Eventually I'd like to figure out how get the gitk version in the terminal but this will do!

Answer (score 2):

You mention (emphasis mine):

> I'd like to see all the commits I've made on all branches, **along with what branch each commit was made on**. I've tried `git log --branches --author="My Name"`, but **that doesn't tell me what branches I've made each commit on**.

**You cannot retrieve information on which branch each commit "was made on"**. Commits don't store that information, they're agnostic to the existence of branches, and are completely independent of them. Furthermore, **branches can share commits**, so you won't be able to definitely tell if a commit was made on one branch or another.

If, instead, you want to know if a particular branch *contains* a commit, you can use

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

to see a list of branches that contains that commit...but that doesn't sound like it's what you're looking for, exactly.

Comment: There are some formulations i would change to explain this properly, but i'm not sure exactly how. The term branch in git is pointer to a commit. The branch does not contain information of which commits it "includes", but each commimt "knows" its' parent commit so given a branch git can follow the path from that commit to its' oldest ancester and in other systems this path would be an actual "branch". It is a branch in the sence that it is a path in a tree, but the path is not a git branch entity per say. The pointer to the youngest commit in the path is a git branch.

Comment: @Cupcake and @scy7he - thanks for the responses. What I'm currently doing is manually switching over to each branch I've worked on and using `git log` to view my commit history per branch. I'm also using the `--graph` option on a branch to show commit history with branch information. I'd like a command that I could hypothetically run independent of a branch with all my work on all branches showing (ideally to show [a similar graph](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any command out of below three to get your desired output:

> 1. git log --pretty=format:"%ad:%an:%d:%B" **--all** --author=My-name
> 2. git log --graph **--all** --topo-order --decorate --oneline --boundary
>      --author=My-name
> 3. git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset -%C(red)%d%Creset %s
>      %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' **--all** --author=My-name

You can also use **--branches** instead of **--all**, in case running for a specific branch.
**--all** by default give you output for all branches.